# php multiple file upload not working at server

Tags: php, file-upload, upload

I've shared hosting and there is a script to upload multiple files at once at server,

It is working **properly in localhost** but it seems **not working at the remote server**.

However while there is **less amount of files**, it works. I've set below `php.ini` variables as,

**php.ini** file on server

```
upload_max_filesize = 100M
post_max_size = 100M
max_file_uploads = 70
post_max_size = 100M
```

I've also set below variables at upload back-end script,

```
ini_set('post_max_size', '100M');
ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '100M');
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
ini_set("memory_limit", "-1");
set_time_limit(0);
ini_set('max_file_uploads', '100');

ini_set('display_errors', 1); 
error_reporting(E_ALL); // E_ALL
```

and still not working.

There is no error / warnings displaying. And also looking in `phpinfo()`, the values are as correct as it should be (as specified above)

**Note :** Generally I've around **800kb** per file and number of files are generally around **25**.

Comment: do you have `write` on your server?

Comment: @jogesh_pi Yes i have ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is solved.

Reason of problem : Changes to the `php.ini` was not reflecting at server. So, contacting hosting provider, the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

change permission of destination folder to 777 at your server and it will be upload. because in local when windows is used windows is not rude about permission to add content to directory but linux is very consicious about permission

Comment: It does..  There is not any problems when there is only few files to upload

Comment: The problem occurs with around 10 files or above. None of them uploads